# JDBC - varbinary(max) out parameter of stored procedure is truncated to 8000 bytes

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, jtds

I'm using Spring Data JPA 1.10.2 with jTds 1.3.1 to call a stored procedure.

The stored procedure has an out parameter, `@data` of type varbinary(max). `@data` contains about ~10,000 bytes.

Here's the stored procedure signature:

```
ALTER procedure [User].[pTest]
      @data varbinary(max) out
      ,@name nvarchar(max) = null
      ,@date datetime
as
begin
.
.
.
```

My entity class is:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "User.getUser", procedureName = "User.pTest", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "data", type = byte[].class),  
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "name", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "date", type = Date.class)
          })
@Data //lombok
public class User {


    // serves no purpose other than to meet
    // JPA requirement
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

The repository code is

```
public interface UserRepository  extends Repository<User, Long> {

    @Procedure("User.pTest")
    byte[] getUserSession(@Param("name") String name, 
            @Param("date") Date date
            );

}
```

My test code is as follows and when I run it I get the error:

```
@Test
public void testGettingApxSession() {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2016,6,5);
    byte[] b = userRepository.getUserSession("myName", cal.getTime());
}
```

When I log out `@data` using:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte a : b) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", a));
    }
```

I noticed that only 8,000 bytes are being returned. When I run the same stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, I notice it has ~10,000 bytes and ends as it should with hex code FFFF.

So, it appears my results are being truncated when running the stored procedure from my Java app.

How can I prevent this truncation? Is there a different data type that I should be specifying for varbinary(max) instead of byte[]?

**Update**

I've also tried Microsoft's JDBC driver (v 6.0.7728.100) and experience the same issue. My guess is that the JDBC drivers (I think) are taking the max to be 8000 based on that being the max number, `n`, you can specify in `varbinary(n)`. However, the max capacity of `varbinary` is much greater than 8000 and is specified by `varbinary(max)`. `varbinary(max)` can hold 2^31 - 1 bytes. See my question and other's answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152239/sql-server-how-can-varbinarymax-store-8000-bytes)

Comment: The 8000 bytes sounds familiar. I recommend Googling like the wind.

Comment: I've tried. Can't seem to find anything definitive

Comment: After quite a bit of research, it appears to be a bug over 2 years old. I hope that I'm wrong though and it has been resolved. This is fatal issue. I can't use the Microsoft SQL Server driver b/c it has its own fatal issue of having to declare default parameters with non-null values.

Comment: I submitted a bug report at  https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/766/

Comment: It tuns out that Microsoft's SQL Server JDBC driver exhibits the same behavior (i.e. it truncates at 8000 bytes). SQL Server used to have a max of 8000 bytes for `varbinary`. I suppose these SQL Server JDBC drivers were never updated to account for the increased size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft's JDBC driver and specify the output parameter type as a `Blob`:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "User.getUser", procedureName = "User.pTest", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "data", type = Blob.class),  
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "name", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "date", type = Date.class)
          })
```

Note: This will not work with jTDS. It will still truncate anything > 8000 bytes.

If the `Blob` needs to be passed back to SQL Server, you must convert back to a byte array as follows:

```
byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
```